# Domain verified but can't activate workspace

Tags: google-workspace, activation

My domain was verified too late to update in trial version. How can I update without going through the entire process again? Feeling frustrated and can't get help.

Tried to upgrade, got sent in an endless circle about updating billing.

Comment: If you have set it up properly (you can check if you have [here](https://knowledge.workspace.google.com/kb/how-to-verify-you-domain-in-google-workspace-000006341)), you need to wait 48 hours for it to be updated.